# javascript soap error calling asp.net web service

Tags: javascript, asp.net, soap

I have a working ASP.Net test web service, but I keep getting 500 errors as:

```
"System.InvalidOperationException: Request format is invalid: text/xml.
   at System.Web.Services.Protocols.HttpServerProtocol.ReadParameters()
   at System.Web.Services.Protocols.WebServiceHandler.CoreProcessRequest()
"
```

when I call it with javascript.

It is a simple web service that takes a single parameter as a string and returns it to the client.  Please help!

[link to code here](http://pastebin.com/L9JHsk1z)

Comment: Code? Hard to help if we don't know what you tried.

Comment: Try putting in the full path to the Web Service rather than relative, other than that make sure the JS is on the same server. Note the Same-origin policy http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Same_origin_policy that will limit your JS calling to only directories at the same level or above. Are you able to call directly in the browser?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For those of you who this might help, the issue was setting the SOAPAction in teh header correctly:

$.ajax({
      type: "post",
      url: target,
      contentType: "text/xml",
      data: soapBody,
      dataType: "xml",
      processData: false,
      beforeSend: function( xhr ){
         **xhr.setRequestHeader(
            "SOAPAction",
            "http://blahblah.com/Services/MethodName"
         );**
      },
....

Answer (score 0):

Make sure that your `mess` variable doesn't contain GET-style query string like `'?a=1&b=2'`. You need to send it in POST format, for example in JSON. Try to change `contentType` to `contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8"`

```
$.ajax({
                url: service,
                type: "POST",
                dataType: "xml",
                data: '{key: value}',
                complete: endTest,
                error: processError,
                contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
        });
```